# Accessing embedded documents of mongodb using JSON

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

The question is: Can I access the embedded documents of a documents in mongodb using JSON selectors after returning the outer document. Let me explain the question with an example:

Suppose **Comments** have an embedded documents **Users**. Now first I return Comments document using the code:

```
var comments = db.Comments.find();
```

And then I use JSON syntax to return the embedded documents, as mongodb uses JSON objects to store documents (so far I understand/know):

```
var users = comments['Users'];
```

I know it is not possible to return embedded documents in mongodb and the way to access Users would be to make seperate document of Users. But, still, I am just asking out of curiosity if this logic would work, as it will help me a lot in coding node.js with mongodb.

Hope that everyone understands the question.

**Note:** The example is just imaginary so please don't comment about the example being right or wrong, the basic purpose was just to make my question understandable with ease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the structure of Comment:

```
  {
    _id,
    Users: [
      {
        name
      }
    ]
  }
```

You can do what you want by aggregate:

```
  db.Comments.aggregate([
    {$unwind:{path:'$Users'}},
    {$project:{'name':'$Users.name', _id: 0}}
  ])
```

Comment: This also gives the required result. But, Actually I wanted to know if my approach was correct.

Comment: Also, What does _id=0 would play the role while projecting?

Comment: If you use `var comments = db.Comments.find();`, comments is an array of comment, so you can access the users of the first comments by comments[0]['Users']

Comment: By default _id will be return even you don't project it by `_id: 1`, so if you don't need _id in return object, you must tell mongodb by `_id: 0`.